# what does this error code mean in RStudio

Tags: r

I am trying to run dada2 within RStudio. Normally I would run it in Windows. However because I want to run cutadapt as well I have had to create a Linux VM. With some help I now have dada2 and cutadapt installed on my VM. I have copied over my R code which works in RStudio in Windows. I have editted the code on my VM so that it points towards the correct directories, e.g. replaced "c:\Rtemp" with "~/Rtemp".  I believe I have done this correctly as RStudio reads in dada2 and then my files just like it does when I start the script in RStudio in Windows. However I then get error messages that I don't get when I run the script in RStudio in windows.

```
fnFs <- sort(list.files(path, pattern="_R1_001.fastq", full.names = TRUE))
fnRs <- sort(list.files(path, pattern="_R2_001.fastq", full.names = TRUE))

sample.names <- sapply(strsplit(basename(fnFs), "_"), `[`, 1)
plotQualityProfile(fnFs[1:2])
Error in (function (cond)  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'dirPath' in selecting a method for function 'qa': IncompatibleTypes
  message: error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'which': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'alphabetFrequency': invalid class “BStringSet” object: undefined class for slot "elementMetadata" ("DataTable_OR_NULL")
```

There are no "install" errors so I don't think the problem is missing installs. Is this error message indicating a problem with the amount of memory on my VM?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem while working through the dada2 tutorial.

I fixed it by loading up library(Biostrings) before loading dada2. I was under the impression that dada2 automatically loaded up Biostrings, but this was the fix. Hopefully it works for you.